# Is there a blender script or way to configure Blender to do this (Retopo)

Tags: modeling, scripting

Is there a Blender script out there that lets you basically 'draw' in a 'net' of edges using strokes that you can then fill in using the spider script or something?
Could I possibly just change some settings to have this ability?
I've been doing a lot of retopo work and think just being able to draw in edges with mouse or tablet strokes would be such an efficient and simple way to do it- I've tried Retopoflow and 3D Coat for retopo and both feel needlessly complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Bsurfaces addon:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQb5lHDFjjs
(The video also activates another add-on).

I haven't tried it myself (new blender doesn't work on my laptop)
but looks simple enough for me.